# Getting a variable output from a function in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Bit stuck and need some guidance. I have created a function and I'm trying to get a value output from said function. I need $Value

```
Function Environment {
$title    = 'Environment'
$question = 'What is the environment?'
$choices  = '&A','&B','&C','&D','&E'
$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
switch ($decision)
  {
    0 {
    {'You selected A'}
        if ($decision -eq 0) {
            $value = "A" 
            return $value
            }
      }
    1 {
    {'You selected B'} 
        if ($decision -eq 1) {
          $value = "B" 
          return $value
        }
      }
    2   {
    {'You selected C'}
        if ($decision -eq 2) 
        {
          $value = "C" 
          return $value
        }
    }
    3 {
    {'You selected D'}
        if ($decision -eq 3) 
        {
          $value = "D" 
          return $value
        }
      }  
    4 {
    {'You selected E'}
        if ($decision -eq 4) 
        {
          $value = "E" 
          return $value
        }
      }
  }
}
$test = environment 
$test 

output 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'You selected Prod '
A
```

Tried to get my head round creating a class but couldn't get it working. Any help or advice where to go?

Comment: Works fine with me

Comment: It does output the value but also the 'You have selected prod' I just need the value.

Comment: PowerShell functions will, by design, return all 'unused' output.  If you don't want it to be returned, try something like `Write-Host 'You selected D'`. For other instances where a cmdlet returns a value as a side-effect (e.g. creating a file with `New-Item`, where you don't want the file object), you can pipe it to null and it is just thrown away: `<some-cmdlet> | Out-Null`

Comment: ```{'You selected A'}``` is an expression that creates a ```ScriptBlock``` object - per @boxdog's comments this is not being captured by anything so is being sent to the output stream from the function and is being assigned to ```$test``` as the first element in the return *array* from your call to ```Environment```. If you just want ```$value``` to be returned you need to *not return* the scriptblock - you can do this by using ```write-host "You selected A"``` to write to the console directly rather than return the value from the function.

Comment: Also, you don't need all the ```if ($decision -eq ...) { ... }``` inside your cases - the case condition itself ensures the value of ```$decision``` when it enters the branch, so you can just ```return "A"```, ```return "B"```, etc inside the case statements...

Comment: Thank you boxdog and mclayton.  Appreciate the help and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Function Environment {
$title    = 'Environment'
$question = 'What is the environment?'
$choices  = '&A','&B','&C','&D','&E'
$decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
switch ($decision)
  {
    0 {
   
        if ($decision -eq 0) {
            $value = "A" 
            return $value
            }
      }
    1 {
    
        if ($decision -eq 1) {
          $value = "B" 
          return $value
        }
      }
    2   {
   
        if ($decision -eq 2) 
        {
          $value = "C" 
          return $value
        }
    }
    3 {
    
        if ($decision -eq 3) 
        {
          $value = "D" 
          return $value
        }
      }  
    4 {
    
        if ($decision -eq 4) 
        {
          $value = "E" 
          return $value
        }
      }
  }
}
$test = environment 
$test
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a little more simple. The `$decision` value makes a perfect index into an array for the result to be returned. Since this is already an interactive script, using `Write-Host` is appropriate.

```
function Environment {
    $title    = 'Environment'
    $question = 'What is the environment?'
    $choices  = '&A','&B','&C','&D','&E'
    $decision = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $question, $choices, 1)
    $Results = @('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
    Write-Host "You selected $($Results[$decision])"
    return $Results[$decision]
}
$test = Environment 
$test
```

Comment: If you want to code-golf it a bit you could even do ```$result = $choices[$decision].Substring(1)`; write-host "You selected $result"; return $result``` - that only works because all the ```$choices``` are 2 characters and you want the last character as the result., but in this case it's fine :-)